# All Ionic dependencies not found

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to write a ionic app based on the sidemenu basis. One view that I am creating is a login view on which the sidemenu should be deactivated. Therefore I need the dependency variable $ionicView.
This leads to the error
Unknown provider: $ionicViewProvider <- $ionicView <- LoginController

The same error appears when trying to access $ionicConfigProvider.

Login.module.js:

```
    angular.module("Login", ['ionic']);
```

Login.Controller.js:

```
angular.module("Login")
    .controller("LoginController", function($ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicView){
        var thisRef = this;

        thisRef.Username = "";
        thisRef.Password = "";


        $ionicView.beforeEnter(function() {
            $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
        });

        $ionicView.beforeLeave(function(){
            $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I conclude from the Ionic forum (http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-ionicview-with-ionic-nightly/13666), is that you don't inject $ionicView directly in your controller, but rather use it in your controller.

```
angular.module("Login")
.controller("LoginController", function($ionicSideMenuDelegate){

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
        //Do whatever you want here
    });
    var thisRef = this;

    thisRef.Username = "";
    thisRef.Password = "";


    $ionicView.beforeEnter(function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
    });

    $ionicView.beforeLeave(function(){
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
    });
});
```

Read the documentation on what is possible with $ionicView: http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionView/ under 'View LifeCycle and Events'

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem with my ionic sidemenu app.

To fix this problem i followed the ionic documentation:
[Ionic View](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

And update my ionic bundle version lib to the final version.

You can update in bower.json file, change the version to ionic-bower#1.3.1"

See this codepen to help you

```
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/LucasES/pen/yaVVqY?editors=1111)